# ApplescriptObjC call to NSMakePoint results in exc_bad_access error

Tags: cocoa, applescript, exc-bad-access, applescript-objc

This problem really puzzles me, since AppleScriptObjC should handle garbage collection just fine on its own.

Anyway, the steps to reproduce this error are:

1. Create a new Cocoa-AppleScript-Application project
2. Insert single call to `NSMakePoint` anywhere in the project's `nameAppDelegate.applescript` file. The file should now look something like this:

   ```
   script testAppDelegate
       property parent : class "NSObject"

       on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
           -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
           set single_point to NSMakePoint(5, 10) of current application
           display alert "X-value of point: " & x of single_point
       end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

       on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
           -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
           display alert "Terminating"
           return current application's NSTerminateNow
       end applicationShouldTerminate_ 
   end script
   ```
3. Run the application

The above application will launch and display the alert `"X-value of point: 5.0"` (as expected), but immediately after the alert it will crash with the following `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in the  file `main.m`: [main.m error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RCSO.png)

Thus, somewhere a call is being made to an object that no longer exists. If we profile the application with `NSZombies` enabled, it confirms that a zombie has been messaged and gives this additional info: [zombie info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRhNQ.png)

I've also tried the same thing with `NSMakeRange` and `NSMakeRect` instead, and it gives exactly the same result. I suspect every call to a Core Foundation function will crash the application this way. However, if we as an example call stringValue() of a NSTextField, it works just fine.

Putting the call outside of `applicationWillFinishLaunching_` does not solve it either. So what am I doing wrong?

I'm using XCode 4.3.3 on OSX Lion 1.7.4

---

**EDIT:** After some further research, I realized I do not need to call `NSMakePoint`, I could just create an AppleScript record like `{|x|:0, |y|:0}` and it will work just like an NSPoint object. So that solves it, I guess.

Comment: Admittedly I do not know or use AppleScriptObjC. However I can see that NSPoint, NSRange, and NSRect all have something in common. They are not objective-c pointer objects. They are c-structures. That's probably the issue since they all fail. Your probably trying to release memory for them but they're not objects with a memory pointer that needs to be released. Maybe AppleScriptObjC can only handle pointers and objects? That would also explain why NSString methods work because it's an object.

Comment: If you’re on Lion, then AppleScriptObjC apps _must_ be built with Objective-C garbage collection enabled.  However, Obj-C GC makes zombie objects impossible by definition — if you got a zombie warning, that suggests you have it disabled, which would definitely cause trouble of the sort you saw, so check your build settings.  AppleScriptObjC apps targeting Mountain Lion (10.8) or later may be built with Obj-C GC off, and your code works fine as-is there.  (Well, probably.  I actually verified it on Mavericks (10.9), but not much in AppleScriptObjC changed between Mountain Lion and Mavericks.)